# Display names of non existent users in comments are a bit too decorated in iOS

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, design, ios-app

Occasionally when a question is migrated, that question has content (comments or answers) from users who still don't have account on the migration target site. On the regular, desktop site, that results in a simple, plain black text username. (as it should be, as there's no account.)

[image: Desktop view of comments on migrated question]

In iOS, though, they get a bit of extra decoration, which leaves them looking almost like the Asker's own comments. I feel that this may be slightly confusing (it confused me!) and the decoration should be removed.

[image: iOS view of comments on migrated question]

As you can see, they're bold, dark font and they have a highlight background like the Asker's, which has a paler blue text.

[image: Unregistered user comment vs OP comment]

Comment: Also note the Asker's username (Florian) looks like a link to their profile but it too is an unregistered account, so there is no link. This should also probably be fixed. What gives it away as unregistered is the lack of avatar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.3.0.

The problem here is that we highlight commenters if they have the same user ID as the OP **and** we treat deleted/missing users as having the user ID `0`.  So the app was highlighting any migrated commenter because there was a migrated OP.  Starting in 1.6.2, this bug will also affect migrated answerers and editors in the revision list, since we're also highlighting if they're the OP.

Now we only highlight if the ID matches and is not zero.

Comment: `Brian.Clone().CopyTo("android app");`